# AsyncTask unable to download file from external site

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm working on my first Android app but I can't seem to make it work properly. This app should download, on click, a file (a pdf, to be specific) from a site (in this case, my personal site) and save it on the SDCard.
I looked around here and found that I should use an AsyncTask for this purpose and this is the code I came up with:

```
package it.uniroma3.tirocinioandroid;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button dlbutton;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dlbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dlbutton);
        dlbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Currently downloading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        Log.i("Main", "finito onCreate");

    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //TODO sistemare il menù
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.dlbutton:
            DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
            downloadFile.execute("http://dragon-nest.net/catalogo.pdf");
            Log.i("Main", "finito onClik");
            break;
        }

    }

    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                Log.i("Main", "connected");
                // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                Log.i("Main", "input set");
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath().concat("download/catalogo.pdf"));
                Log.i("Main", "output set");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("ERROR_TAG", e.getMessage());
                    return "fine";
                }
            String s ="fine";
            Log.i("Main", "end download");
            return s;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog.show();
            Log.i("Main", "end preExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.i("Main", "end postExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
            Log.i("Main", "update...");
        }


    }
}
```

However, it seems to be unable to connect to the site to begin the download. From the Logcat it shows that it generates an exception when it tries to connect which is caught and blocks everything before the download can really begin.

Here is also the manifest for the app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.uniroma3.tirocinioandroid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="it.uniroma3.tirocinioandroid.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="it.uniroma3.tirocinioandroid.FileDownloader"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_file_downloader" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

By the way, I tried to see if maybe it was my site acting funky, but I can download the file from the browser just fine. I also tried with another file from another site but I get the same problem.
This happens to me both on the AVD and my tablet so I don't think it's an AVD-related issue.

Comment: what exception you are getting? Please put that stacktrace. And, if the site you are downloading is on https:// please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your Manifest. There is no such tag as `<user-permission>`, change it to `<uses-permission>`.

If this won't help change declaration of your `connection` to `HttpURLConnection` and use it like this:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

I don't think it's really very important, but I use it that way and it works every time (casting to HttpsURLConnection may be required depending on declared protocol scheme).

Comment: You're completely right, I misspelled the permission, thanks for pointing it out, it now works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try.. this out

Instead of the catch statement

```
catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("ERROR_TAG", e.getMessage());
                return "fine";
            }
```

catch specific exceptions such as IOEXCEPTION or any other Exception because by the

```
catch(Exception e)
```

statement the Async Task catches all the exception that has occured

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me in locating another error I got after fixing this one and solving it.

Answer (score 0):

this code worked with me !

```
 protected class myClass extends AsyncTask{
  @Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    try{

        File cacheDir = new  File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"FolderName");
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
           cacheDir.mkdirs();
        File f=new File(cacheDir,"q.mp3");
         text1.setText("file");
        URL url = new URL("your link"); 
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(f);

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;
                    int count=0;
                                while ((count = input.read()) != -1) {
                        total++;
                       Log.e("while","A"+total);

                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();

        }

    catch (Exception e) { 
                  e.printStackTrace();}

    return null;
}
```

}